# C Language: how do I evaluate the return value of a signal handler?

Tags: c, signals, interrupt-handling

In the code I'm writing it would be very useful to check the return value of a signal handler to make sure the signal was received or not. So, for example, if I have something of this kind:

```
Message m;
sig_t s = signal(SIGALRM, sigalrm);
alarm(DURATION);
int status = msgrcv(msg_id, &m, sizeof(m.appointment), destination_mailbox, 0);
```

what is going to happen is the program will block as soon as it reaches the msgrcv command, because it will be waiting for a message. However, if it does not recieve a message after the DURATION seconds, the alarm signal will wake it up, and status will equals -1.

Now, ideally, let's say I would like to make sure that the program woke up due to the alarm and nothing else. Say, for example, there was an error in msgrcv,and thus the program woke up, but the status is still -1 and m is empty.

The man entry for the return value of signal states

> signal() returns the previous value of the signal handler, or SIG_ERR
> on  error.   In  the
> event of an error, errno is set to indicate the cause.

If I try to print the value of sig_t s, after the signal handler had been called, how would I do it? This prints "signal (nil)".

```
 printf("signal %p\n", s);
```

So, how do I take care of this return value if I want to so something like

```
if(s == a state where the handler was never called)
      do A;
else
      do B;
```

Comment: `typedef void (*sig_t) (int);`  As you can see, a signal handler is a function that does not return a value.

Comment: Invoking `signal` does not invoke the handler.  If `signal` returns NULL, that just means that no handler was previously in place.  It does not mean that no SIGALRM has been received.  If you want to know that your handler has been called, have the handler change the value of a global sig_atomic_t (really, that's all your handler should do anyway).  In the main process, check when that value is modified.

Comment: @WilliamPursell damn it, I was trying to avoid globals at all costs. But you're suggesting I use a global of the type sig_atomic_t?

Comment: hope you are resetting `alarm` if `msgrcv` returns in time.

Comment: @IrAM Yes, I briefly thought about that, so I will take this opportunity and ask: all I need is check if msgrcv != -1 and if so, do alarm(0) and it will be canceled, right?

Comment: success or failure does not matter once `msgrcv` returns you have to make `alarm(0)` then handle the scenario

Comment: Signal handlers require the use of file scope variables — global or static.  That is practically unavoidable.  With the regular signal handler, the only information available to the signal handler is the signal number.  POSIX provides [`sigaction()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html)
which provides option `SA_SIGINFO` and passes much more information to the handler, but still no access to programmer-controlled data — if you have to access data in the signal handler, it has to be at least file scope data.

Comment: Note that the pointer returned by `signal()` can be `SIG_IGN`, `SIG_DFL`, `SIG_ERR` or a pointer to a function.  It is likely that `SIG_DFL` is `((void(*)(int))0)`.  The value returned by `msgrcv()` will be `-1` and `errno == EINTR` if the alarm timed out (and `sigalrm()` returns rather than exits).  You could also have `static volatile sig_recvd = 0;` as a file scope variable and `void sigalrm(int signum) { sig_recvd = signum; }` and then test the value in `sig_recvd` to determine whether you got an alarm signal rather than an interrupt or terminate signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [`msgrcv`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/msgrcv.html) is interrupted by a signal, it should return `-1` and `errno` should be set to `EINTR` (unless the behavior has been changed using [`sigaction`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html)).

So to check that case :

```
int status = msgrcv(/*...*/);
if (status == -1) {
    if (errno == EINTR)) {
        /* interrupted by signal */
    }
    else {
        /* other error */
    }
}
```

If you need to check specifically for a `SIGALRM` interrupt, you can have your signal handler set a global [`sig_atomic_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/sig_atomic_t) variable, and then check that after `msgrcv` returns.

Comment: *unless the behavior has been changed using `sigaction`* POSIX imposes no requirement that I have found for `msgrcv()` to be restarted instead of interrupted. [The behavior of `msgrcv()` can not be changed on Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgrcv.2.html) to be restarted:  "`msgrcv()` is never automatically restarted after being interrupted by a signal handler, regardless of the setting of the `SA_RESTART` flag when establishing a
         signal handler."